# Is there a tool to visualize the citation network which works with Google Scholar?

Tags: citations, software, literature-search

I know about tools like [CitNet Explorer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi5hPGR2o_eAhUMgHMKHbFTB3IQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.citnetexplorer.nl%2F&usg=AOvVaw01-A_uQFe03PdGig2vJLGA) and [VOSviewer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjVj_6X2o_eAhUJCRoKHfuGAJEQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vosviewer.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3iSbIxFmAYcupPSgHzKSvc), but they only work with Web of Science, which doesn't contain many papers I'd like to have in the network.

Is there any software, which does the same thing with data from Google Scholar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, at the time of writing, Google Scholar does not define an API to access data, so presumably no software exists. Beyond Google Scholar and the tools you've already mentioned, you could try  https://www.semanticscholar.org or https://aminer.org. (I'm a little unsure what you mean by *citation network*, so perhaps they don't satisfy your needs.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at them. By *citation network* I mean that I put one paper into the software and it'll give me all the papers cited in the first one and all the papers cited in them up to n-th level. Usually, this leads to come clusters of papers and you can presume, which papers should be chosen for some systematic review.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a package called Scopus2CitNet to convert the .CSV table of citations downloaded from Scopus to a format that is readable by CitNet Explorer. The tutorial video and links to download the package is here:
[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_1ClVf77AE), [R package](https://github.com/MichaelBoireau/Scopus2CitNet/).

For VOS I would suggest you also try getting data as a .CSV from other databases like "[Dimensions](https://app.dimensions.ai/discover/publication)".

Remember to save your search terms as a text file for the "methods" section of the review!